# Event handler when a user is playing a game

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am unable to find an event handler using discord.js that fires when a user starts streaming or playing a game.

I have attempted to use the userUpdate (which I understand wouldn't work because it pertains to the current user, being the bot), and also the guildMemberUpdate event.

```
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldUser, newUser) => {
    if(oldUser.user.username === "Test"){
        if(newUser.user.game.streaming){
            //find the channel and post a message
        }
    }
});
```

When adding a breakpoint, I never hit the first if statement. The event doesn't seem to fire off of a user's "activity" or "status" changing. Is there such an event for this?

EDIT for clarity: I've been using my own user on the discord server. I will go from no game being played, to playing a game or streaming, and the event handler is never hit. Picture included to make sure you can see the status I'm trying to get to trigger the event.

[image]

Comment: A. "*...[`userUpdate`] pertains to the current user, being the bot...*" The event will be emitted when a user updates *something* to do with their user profile, rather than their server-specific settings. For example, it would be triggered by any user changing their username or discriminator. B. Is the listener you're showing nested inside of another? If this is the case, it won't be attached until the outer event is emitted. C. Can you debug your code a bit by adding `console.log('emitted')` (or something similar) as the very first line of your listener function, and share the results?

Comment: A. Neither userUpdate, nor guildMemberUpdate handled this. B. No it is not. C. It's never hitting the listener, but I'm running it using VSCode so I can use breakpoints as well.

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using? These events work as expected for me.

Comment: Latest, 11.5.1. I added a picture to make sure we're on the same page as to what I mean when I say "playing a game". It was fired when I, say, added a permission. But not for playing a game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client's [`presenceUpdate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate) event is what you're looking for. It'll be emitted when a user's game status changes.

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
  // do your thing
});
```